# Keep "in voltage" stable of switching regulator

Tags: filter, switching-regulator

I powered a Raspberry Pi pico (**RP**) from the Atari Joystick port of a Sega Master System (**SMS**) (it should be able to supply 5 V and max 100 mA).

RP using [RT6150B buck-boost](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6150A=RT6150B/DS6150AB-05.pdf) like this (+5 V from joystick port is connected to VBUS).
[image]

I measured the RP current usage and it's about 30 mA and it's working fine.

But when I connect the RP to the SMS I hear a buzzing noise in the audio (I mean on the SMS connected to a TV).

I did some research and found [that someone](https://pico-adc.markomo.me/PSU-Noise/) (I do not have oscilloscope yet) measured the voltage drop on the 5 V (USB VBUS) of the RP board and it looks like this:

[image]

Is this voltage drop noise/ripple causing noise in SMS audio (also there is some video disruption - a darker field which is "walking" down to up on the screen - if I'm correctly reading the image the ripple has 45 kHz harmonic which is out of sync with PAL signal)?

Is it possible to filter it out without modifying the power supply of the SMS itself (which is probably an old linear regulator 10 to 5 V, edit: it's a 7805). In other words can I make "in 5V" clear of this noise?

Edit: Yes, I tried to switch RP Pico to PWM mode which theoretically should be low noise but the problem is still there.

Edit 2: Overall RP application should allow connecting an HID gamepad to the SMS. Basically PAD_XX comes from SMS which keeps them pulled up and when you ground them the SMS reads it as a button press. RP reads HID reports, parses them and sends them to the pins which cause a transistor to ground PAD_XX.

[image]

Comment: RP?  SMS?  I'm sure you think these abbreviations are clear to all, but please _edit your question_ to expand them into real phrases.

Comment: Also, an explanation of what you're using the RaspberryPi power for, and maybe a sketch of your overall system would be helpful.

Comment: @TimWescott I've added overall sketch ... it's working fine but I need to get rid of this noise ... noise is there even if there is no gamepad connected to the RP

Comment: Please show your measurement setup.

Comment: as I wrote I do not have oscilloscope so I'm using measurements from [here](https://pico-adc.markomo.me/PSU-Noise/)

Comment: C1 should be sufficient filter, but it's presumably not. Put another C similar to C1 from VBUS to ground, with an L similar to L1 in series with D1.

Comment: @Neil_UK thnx, I will try

Comment: Insufficient decoupling. Probably also Y-capacitor leakage issue but you need to show your entire setup to tell for sure.

Comment: @winny of power or you are talking about aplication itself (transistors) or measurements ?

Comment: Bottom schematic shows zero decoupling.

Comment: Becuase there is no need as U1(raspberry pi pico board) contains first schematic (PSU) **so bottom schematic contains only digital signals** and PSU(again, integratad in U1) contains C1(Vin) and C2(Vout) decoupling